# How do I show a loading state while React components are being mapped from a large array of data?

Tags: reactjs

I understand how to set a loading state while data is fetching from my API, but how do I set a loading state when the data is already retrieved but is being mapped into components?

I have a component that waits to be rendered while the data is being retrieved like so:

```
const [retrieving, setRetrieving] = useState(false)

useEffect(async () => {
  setRetrieving(true)

  // make an API request and set data

  setRetrieving(false)
 }
}, [pageId])

 return (
 {retrieving ? (
      <LoadingSpinner />
    ) : (
      <MyComponent data={data} />
    )}
)
```

Inside of that component, I am mapping that data to output some child components for example:

```
{data.map((item) => (
              <ChildComponent key={item.id} data={item} />
            ))}
```

When that data changes for the same component, there's a split second where the previous data shows in my component before the current data is rendered. I want to polish it a bit so I show a loading spinner while the appropriate data is being mapped. Is there any way to do that?

UPDATE: So I figured out my issue if anyone finds this through google. I was using the same 'retrieving' state for two different API calls. The initial API call was setting the retrieving state to false before the second API call was finished, hence displaying my component before the state was retrieved. My code example was too sparse to show that unfortunately. I'll try posting more code in future questions.

Comment: When `retrieving` changes to true, the `data` should have changed to the updated value at the same time, so if your implementation is correct, the previous `data` will not be displayed for a moment. You can write the details of the code, such as where and how the `data` is changed and where the pageId is passed from, to understand it better.

Comment: The pageId is coming from a query parameter (same page/components but different data being fetched depending on the id).

Comment: While fetching new data from api you can make `data` empty so that when new data are being loaded from api then previous data do not show.

Comment: @MohammadAbdulAlim That works but now I have a split second where the data is empty/component is blank before it suddenly appears. I'm hoping to show a loading spinner then, but I can't do it for a case when the array is empty because in some cases I won't be expecting data

Answer (score 0):

Using .map shouldn't take long at all.
I think the issue sounds more from your useEffect. Maybe move the setRetrieving(true) line to where ever the trigger for changing pageId is.

Could you possibly post some more code (maybe upload it to codepen) so we could have a loot at it more?

You could also have a look at using something like React-Query as that has alot of what you are asking for pre built.
https://react-query.tanstack.com/